# How to calculate values using for-end and if-else in Octave?

Tags: octave

I need to calculate variable `Nfj` in the following equation:

```
ea_M = (sf/E)*(2*Nfj)^b + ef*(2*Nfj)^c
```

so that it is equal to 4 different values of `ea`: 5.0900e-04, 4.3626e-04, 3.6358e-04, and 2.9084e-04. The results should be 4 values of `Nfj` which should be stored in `results`. I am rounding because I think that it is not possible to calculated exactly equal values of `ea`, without rounding the equality would always be false.

I wrote for it this code, but it does not work as expected: the script runs for a very long time without any results. How can I fix it to work correctly?

```
sf = 882.07;
ef = 0.59;
b = -0.102969;
c = -0.58;
E = 210000;
ea = [5.0900e-04; 4.3626e-04; 3.6358e-04; 2.9084e-04]

for pos = 1:length(ea)
  for Nfj = 1e3:10:1e12
    ea_M = (sf/E)*(2*Nfj)^b + ef*(2*Nfj)^c;
    if  round(ea_M * 10^5)/10^5 == round(ea(pos) * 10^5)/10^5;
      disp(ea_M)
      disp(Nfj)
      results(pos) = Nfj;
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You aren't using your `Nfj` variable, so `ea_M` should be always the same.

Comment: just so i follow, instead of calculating Nfj, you're stepping through all possible Nfj's and comparing it to the actual calculated value, then storing that Nfj if it's close to what you calculated. It looks a bit inefficient, as you're doing a billion iterations to get four values. One specific problem I see is none of the variables in the ea_M line (sf E Ns b ef c) look like they would change in any way as you're moving through your loop, so if those inputs don't change, you're going to get the same ea_M each time that line occurs.

Comment: Hello, I have corrected the script according to your comments. Ns in the original script should be Nfj. Unfortunatelly the script runs very long time without the results so any sugestions for improvement are welcome. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So you can't solve your equation for `Nfj`? How about trying a numerical solver? Brute-force trying all possible values of `Nfj` is going to be terribly inefficient, and you are likely to skip the actual value that would make the equality work (you try every 10th value, and you round to 5 decimals, do you see an increase of 1e-5 for every `Nfj` that you try?)

Comment: Hello Cris, I don't have experience with solving such equations in Octave. I know that my approach is probably ineficient but I do not know anything better. Could you give me a hint how to solve it with numerical solver in Octave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying every 10<sup>th</sup> value, from 10<sup>3</sup> to 10<sup>12</sup>: there are 10<sup>11</sup> values here to try! This is of course a lot. You will be searching for ever, and you might skip the actual value that would make the equality true.

If you are not able to solve the equation manually, you can use a numerical solver. Let's first print the function:

```matlab
sf = 882.07;
ef = 0.59;
b = -0.102969;
c = -0.58;
E = 210000;

ea_M = @(Nfj) (sf/E)*(2*Nfj).^b + ef*(2*Nfj).^c;

Nfj = logspace(3,12,1000);
plot(Nfj, ea_M(Nfj))
set(gca, 'xscale', 'log')
```

[image: plot generated by code above]

It looks like this function is nicely monotonic, and the four values you are looking for are in the interval of 10<sup>3</sup> to 10<sup>12</sup> you were searching. To find where it equals one of your values, we can subtract that value and find where it equals zero. You can very quickly narrow down your search if you start at a point where the function is larger than zero, and one where it is smaller than zero. You halve the interval every time, keeping the half of the interval that contains the zero crossing. The [`fzero`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) function does just this.

```matlab
ea = [5.0900e-04; 4.3626e-04; 3.6358e-04; 2.9084e-04];
results = zeros(size(ea));
for pos = 1:numel(ea)
   results(pos) = fzero(@(Nfj) ea_M(Nfj) - ea(pos), [1e3,1e12]);
end
results
```

In MATLAB, this code runs in a small fraction of a second and outputs:

```
results =

   1.0e+10 *

    0.0429
    0.1849
    1.0627
    9.1919
```

and `ea_M(results) - ea` is approximately zero.

---

A few notes on the code I posted here:

1. `ea_M` is defined as an anonymous function. This makes it easier to reuse the expression, rather than writing it over and over again. I replaced `^` with `.^` to allow this function to do the computation on an array of `Nfj` values at once, rather than only single values. This is necessary for the `fzero` call.
2. I plotted the function on a logarithmic scale, because this function calls for that. The same is not true for all functions.
3. I preallocated the `results` array, you should avoid increasing the size of an array in a loop.